# Issues with .length returning as undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm building a project that uses a function called Chat.fetch(); it's an asynchronous function that pulls an array of strings from the server. It's an ajax function that for purposes of the project is already defined, I just have to call it correctly. There is another function we are given called Chat.display() which takes a string and displays it in bulleted form on the console. Right now this is what I've got: I'm getting an error that says cannot read property length of undefined. So I guess.length is undefined for superArray? The goal is to create this function and use it as the call back function for Chat.fetch(). Do you guys have any idea why I'm getting this .length error? I'm pretty confused. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://chatbuilder.hackreactor.com/ChatBuilder.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>


    Chat.guide.start();
    </script>

    <h2>Borken Chat</h2>

    <input class="draft" type="text"/> <button class="send" disabled>send</button>



    <ul class="messages">

  <script>
    var list;
    var superArray=[];
    darray=function(superArray){
      var y=superArray.length;
      for(i=0;i<y;i++){
        Chat.display(x[i]);
      }
    }
    Chat.fetch(darray(list));
  </script>

    </ul>
```

Comment: <script>
    var superArray;
    darray=function(superArray){
      var y=superArray.length;
      for(i=0;i<y;i++){
        Chat.display("x[i]");
      }
    }
    Chat.fetch(darray(superArray));
  </script>  //gives me the same error. says .length is not defined for superArray.length...

Comment: you say Chat.fetch is asynchronous, in that case surely you should be passing it a function to call once the operation is finished (or possibly it returns a promise). Passing it an empty array, or indeed the output of the function `darray` (which returns `undefined`!) does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Cause you are sending `list` as the superArray argument and `list` indeed in undefined 
You need to send the superArray:

```
Chat.fetch(darray(superArray));
```

Comment: It's still giving me the same error, even after I change from list to superArray.

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` and it seems like the chat framework error [http://jsfiddle.net/upzTY/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/upzTY/2/)

Comment: thanks man. i've followed up with the instructor. could you elaborate on what a chat framework error is?

Answer (score 0):

you pass the variable 'list' to the function

```
Chat.fetch(darray(list));
```

list is undefined in this moment so it's normal that you can't use 'length' on it.
i don't know what's the correct use of this function, but i think you have to pass 'superArray' to the function and not 'list'

Comment: Thanks for the response I changed it and I still get the same message   <script>
    var superArray;
    darray=function(superArray){
      var y=superArray.length;
      for(i=0;i<y;i++){
        Chat.display("x[i]");
      }
    }
    Chat.fetch(darray(superArray));
  </script>

Comment: try to initialize the superArray this way:
var superArray = new Array();

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the variable by setting it to 0.  `var list = 0`;